# Disable 'app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"' for child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a parent fragment with `CoordinatorLayout` for scrolling inside nested fragments but I want to disable `ToolBar` 'hiding' for a fragment that doesn't need it.

3 out of 5 fragments have a `TabLayout` that it *is* needed but the other does not need it.

How do I disable it for these other fragments?

Answer (score 3):

you could use the help of `ViewCompat` class to disable/enable the `nestedScroll` such: `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(myView,false);`

Comment: This does not seem to do anything. Is this supposed to be on the container view or the nested `RecylerView` ?

Comment: nested views, such as recyclerview or nestedScrollView